# reducing c++ asio timer scheduling latency

Tags: c++, boost-asio

ASIO timer sheduling code seems to have a latency around 1us (a cost of a syscall).

Benchmark

```
void asio_timer_scheduling_benchmark(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ctx = asio::io_context{1};
  auto timer = asio::system_timer{ctx};

  for ([[maybe_unused]] auto _ : state) {
    timer.expires_after(5ms);
    timer.async_wait([&](auto&&){}); // <-- this one
    timer.cancel();
    ctx.poll();
  }
}

BENCHMARK(asio_timer_scheduling_benchmark);
```

Says

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                    Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asio_async_op_post_benchmark              84.2 ns         84.1 ns      8286940
asio_timer_scheduling_benchmark            400 ns          400 ns      1758090
```

And perf says

```
 45.23%  bdx_benchmarks  libc-2.28.so         [.] timerfd_settime
  8.18%  bdx_benchmarks  [vdso]               [.] __vdso_clock_gettime
```

Questions

1. Curiosity - why syscalls for timers?
2. Practical - Is rolling my own timer wheel on a dedicated thread is the only option to lower this latency or something can be done within ASIO to improve it? I am happy with microsecond precision, but not scheduling latency.

Comment: This question is about boost-asio, right?

Comment: How would you implement a timer that is scheduled to fire via select/epoll (thus in combination with other I/O, potentially in another thread) without a syscall?

Comment: @bitmask both, boost and standalone

Comment: @rustyx a dedicated scheduler wheel thread posting into the ioloop on completion would be ~100ns

Comment: @bobah but isn't that a trade-off then ? for one you need an extra thread.. i can imagine this leading to worse performance in some applications..

Comment: @darune - it is indeed. my ideal trade-off would be to have scheduling as a by-product of the fact that I am spinning the IO-loop, so don't even need a second thread (theoretically).

Comment: @bobah did you consider fibers (application side threading) ? I know this has drawbacks, just curios

Comment: "posting" an immediate task into the I/O loop cancels the epoll (2 syscalls - epoll_ctl, epoll_wait).

Comment: @rustyx - you are right, in general "the damage" to the event loop should be even worse with `post()`, but in a single-threaded setup, when posting you are already out of the epoll into the user space. And idea I got just now - for very short timers <1us I can probably just repost the handler couple times before actually scheduling anything. Though `post()` is not blazing fast either, ~80ns.